# How to detect that the view or its child has been called draw

Tags: android

I'm developing the scalable layout system.

I want to know how to detect that the view or its child has been called draw.

Below : The code I am using.

```
scaleView = new View(this) {
        private Paint paint = new Paint();

        private View rootView;
        private Rect rootViewRect = new Rect();
        private Rect windowVisibleDisplayFrameRect = new Rect();

        {
            this.rootView = ((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
            this.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowVisibleDisplayFrameRect);
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    postInvalidate();
                }
            }, 0, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            rootView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap drawingCache = rootView.getDrawingCache();

            if (rootViewRect.right == 0) {
                rootViewRect = new Rect(0, 0, rootView.getWidth(), rootView.getHeight());
                return;
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(drawingCache, rootViewRect, windowVisibleDisplayFrameRect, null);

            rootView.destroyDrawingCache();
        }

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            event.setLocation(event.getX() * ((float) rootViewRect.right / windowVisibleDisplayFrameRect.right), event.getY() * ((float) rootViewRect.bottom / windowVisibleDisplayFrameRect.bottom));
            rootView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    };
this.addContentView(scaleView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

I am currently using the timer to call invalidate, but it is slow and require CPU usage.

So I want to invalidate only when the view or its child is changed.

How can I do it?